# HTML File input box doesn't fire fileSelect event and caveat in onchange event - angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-io

I'm using HTML File type control to select and upload a file (using AngularJS). My mark-up is as below:

```
<input id="uploadFile" accept=".csv" type="file" ng-file-select="model.onFileSelect($files)" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)">
```

So when I select any file the fileNameChanged event is fired and not onFileSelect. This works fine so far. However if I select the same file to upload, the fileNameChanged event is not fired (because I'm uploading the same file) but I want to allow user to upload the same file again and again. The onFileSelect event is never fired.

Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: No update on this yet by anyone? Hasn't anyone faced similar issue even with jQuery if not AngularJS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it to work, in the HTML I've added onclick JS event like this:

```
<input id="uploadFile" onclick="myFunction();" accept=".csv" type="file" ng-file-select="model.onFileSelect($files)" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)">

function myFunction() {
  //setting value of null of 0th index coz in my case i allow user to upload only single file.
  //in case of multiple files, you gotta set value to null of the entire array of file list
  //returned by the control
  $('#uploadfile')[0].value = null;
  return true;
}
```

With this, the control won't cache the file name and next time when same file is selected the onChange event would get fired.

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Thx,
Sagar